# Kivy - Update ProgressBar value from Spinner current value

Tags: python, kivy

I have a Spinner and a ProgressBar in kivy. The Spinner is filled with values from 6 to 50. My goal is to pull the current value from the Spinner (string), parse it (to an int) and use the Spinner value on the value property of the ProgressBar. This has to happen everytime the user updates the spinner value. Here is my code:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', False)
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class ApplicationLayout(FloatLayout):

    def spinnerValues(self, min_value, max_value):

        self.possible_values = []
        for k in range(min_value, max_value + 1):
            self.possible_values.append("" + str(k) + "")

        return self.possible_values

    def clearSelection(self):

        self.ids.cb_word.active = False
        self.ids.cb_letters.active = False
        self.ids.cb_lowercase.active = False
        self.ids.cb_uppercase.active = False
        self.ids.cb_repeated_chars.active = False
        self.ids.cb_numbers.active = False
        self.ids.cb_special_chars.active = False
        self.ids.lb_strength.text = ''
        self.ids.pb_strength.value = 0
        self.ids.it_word.text = ''
        self.ids.it_passwords.text = ''

    def currentValue(self, size):
        print(type(int(size)))  # just to ensure that this method can return an int
        return int(size)


class PasswordGeneratorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (67 / 255, 67 / 255, 67 / 255, 1)
        self.title = 'Password Generator'
        return ApplicationLayout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    PasswordGeneratorApp().run()
```

**passwordgenerator.kv**

```
<Spinner@Spinner>
    size_hint:[0.07,0.05]  

<ButtonWidget@Button>
    size_hint:[0.15,0.07]
    font_size:'18sp'
    background_normal: ''
    background_color: (63/255, 191/255, 191/255, 0.6)

<OneWordLabel@Label>
    font_size:'20sp'
    size_hint:[0.1,0.05]    

<MultiWordLabel@Label>
    font_size:'20sp'
    size_hint:[0.25,0.05]

<CheckBox@CheckBox>
    size_hint:[0.05, 0.05]

<TextInput@TextInput>
    size_hint:[0.3,0.06]
    multiline: True

<ProgressBar@ProgressBar>
    size_hint:[0.4,None]

<ApplicationLayout>:
    padding: [30,30,0,0] 
    MultiWordLabel:
        pos_hint:{'y':0.9} 
        text: 'Password length'

    Spinner:
        text_autoupdate: True
        id: sp_passw_length
        pos_hint: {'right':0.32, 'y':0.9}
        values:  root.spinnerValues(6, 50)
        on_text: root.currentValue(self.text)

    ProgressBar:
        id:pb_strength
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.77,'y':0.84}
        value: root.currentValue(sp_passw_length.text)

    OneWordLabel:
        id: lb_strength
        text: 'Strong' 
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.92,'y':0.9}

    OneWordLabel:
        text: 'Include:'
        pos_hint: {'right':0.125, 'y': 0.8}  #fix positioning when screen is maximized

    CheckBox:
        id:cb_word
        pos_hint: {'right':0.19, 'y':0.8}
        active: False
    OneWordLabel:
        text: 'Word'
        pos_hint: {'right':0.275, 'y':0.8}

    TextInput:
        id: it_word
        pos_hint: {'right':0.58, 'y':0.795}  
        disabled: not cb_word.active    

    CheckBox:
        id: cb_letters
        pos_hint: {'right':0.67, 'y':0.8}

    OneWordLabel:
        text: 'Letters:'            
        pos_hint: {'right':0.77, 'y':0.8}    

    CheckBox:
        id: cb_lowercase
        pos_hint: {'right':0.70, 'y':0.73}

    OneWordLabel:
        text: 'Lowercase'
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.815, 'y':0.73}

    CheckBox:     
        id: cb_uppercase
        pos_hint: {'right':0.70, 'y':0.67} 

    OneWordLabel:
        text: 'Uppercase'
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.815, 'y':0.67}

    CheckBox:
        id: cb_numbers
        pos_hint: {'right':0.19, 'y':0.58}

    OneWordLabel:
        text: 'Numbers'
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.30, 'y':0.58}

    CheckBox:
        id: cb_repeated_chars
        pos_hint: {'right':0.51, 'y':0.58}

    MultiWordLabel:
        text: 'Don\'t repeat characters'
        pos_hint: {'right':0.775, 'y':0.58}

    CheckBox:
        id: cb_special_chars
        pos_hint: {'right':0.19, 'y':0.51}

    MultiWordLabel:
        text: 'Special characters'
        pos_hint: {'right':0.425, 'y':0.51}

    OneWordLabel:
        text: 'Quantity:'
        pos_hint: {'right':0.58, 'y':0.51}

    Spinner:
        text_autoupdate: True
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.69, 'y': 0.51}
        values: root.spinnerValues(1, 20)

    ButtonWidget:
        text: 'Generate'
        pos_hint: {'right':0.45, 'y':0.32}

    ButtonWidget:
        text: 'Clear'
        pos_hint: {'right':0.65, 'y':0.32}
        on_press: root.clearSelection()

    MultiWordLabel:
        text: 'Your password(s):'
        pos_hint: {'right': 0.385, 'y':0.15}

    TextInput:
        id: it_passwords
        pos_hint: {'right':0.69, 'y':0.145}
        readonly: True
```

The Spinner and the ProgressBar of interest have the 'sp_passw_length' and 'pb_strength' ids, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is only necessary that you convert the value to int if it is not an empty string:

```
ProgressBar:
    id:pb_strength
    pos_hint: {'right': 0.77,'y':0.84}
    value: root.currentValue(int(sp_passw_length.text)) if sp_passw_length.text != "" else 6
```

Comment: Solved my problem! Thank you so much, @eyllanesc! Didn't know it was that easy, I'm new to Python and Kivy.